# Using a for loop to assign an array to another array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a project where by I used a sorting algorithm to sort an array but I am at the point where I now need to examine different arrays of different sizes and different values. Is there a way I can assign an array to a global array using a for loop
e.g
I have 12 arrays named array1 through to array12 and i need to assign them to a global array called array that is passed in to the sorting algorithm
The 12 arrays are passed in to the array from a file

Comment: Why don't use Collections sorting?

Comment: Instead of having different variables for those arrays, you should just make an array of arrays. This will make things much easier. Also, too broad; show some code!

Comment: This is typically handled by passing array1 through array12 as a parameter to the sort method. Copying to yet another array isn't necessary unless you need to retain the array in its unsorted state.

Comment: @TheRedFox the assignment involves me writing my own sorting algorithms which I have done

Comment: @laune i do need to retain the unsorted array as there are 6 sorting algorithm that need to run all 12 arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having variables that look like `array1`, `array2`, `array3`,..., `array12` is a sure sign that you need a single array instead of all these variables. You should put these arrays into an array of arrays, and use `array[x]` to access them.

For example, instead of

```
int[] array1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
int[] array2 = new int[] {4, 5, 6};
...
int[] array12 = new int[] {34, 35, 36};
```

you would write

```
int[][] array = new int[][] {
    new int[] {1, 2, 3},
    new int[] {4, 5, 6},
    ...
    new int[] {34, 35, 36}
};
```

Now instead of writing `array5` you would write `array[4]` (4, not 5, because indexes of Java arrays are zero-based). This indexing can be done with a `for` loop:

```
int[][] array = new int[][] { ... };
for (int i = 0 ; i != array.length ; i++) {
    callMySort(array[i]);
}
```

or from a `foreach` loop:

```
int[][] array = new int[][] { ... };
for (int[] sortMe : array) {
    callMySort(sortMe);
}
```

Comment: I did this and it gave me an error `int multiArrays[][] = new int[9][9];
   multiArrays[0] = file.getarray1();
   multiArrays[1] = file.getarray2();for(int i = 0;i<12;i++)
    {
     fillArray(multiArrays[i]);
     //array = multiArrays[i];
     try {
      selectionSort(multiArrays[i]);
     } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
      
      e1.printStackTrace();
     }
    }`
    But i get an error

Comment: @FutureSystemsAnalyst That's because you made an array of nine arrays, but you tried to get twelve elements from it. This would cause an "index out of range" exception. You need to either put 12 arrays into `multiArrays`, or change the loop to process 9 elements.